How to reduce the number of wires from digital output sensors
I have about 200 digital output sensors.
One wire will run from one location to another for 24 V power.
They are in sets of 4 and measure magnetic field presence (reed switches maybe).
From the combination of ones of each pair, I gain information that object 1, 2, 3, 4 is in place. In the case one sensor out of 4 fails, the information is not lost (3 would have been enough). The problem is that there are too many cables in the house. Data rate should be in 1 read every minute.
I have seen some electronic components, but I don't know how they work or what were they created for. Multiplexers can receive 4 signals, but I do not understand if they can send one analogic output (maybe; i understand it as a voltage interval: 0-6V means object 1; 6-12 means object 2...) to have only one wire with enough information to differentiate the objects. Another solution may be Arduino, but it seems odd to program a single chip for each pair with a simple logical problem. Other solutions would be to make a circuit, but I hope there is a component specific for this task. Please provide two variants, so I better understand: one expensive, but resilient; and one cheap that does the job.

So the question reduces to “How is this solved normally by people who know electronics?”. Sorry to bother you, but I am a chemist and want to do this.

A pair is two but, a group might be four. What do you mean? What does analogic mean in this context? Have you looked up what it means? Why do you say an Arduino is a PLC? Why do you say Multiplexers can receive 4 signals?

You really need to say what these sensors are measuring and how often the measurements need to be made, that makes a huge difference to any potential design.

So you have 200 bits distributed all across the house and want to collect them once per second/hour/microsecond? Is there local power supply at the sensors or not?

In addition to the previous questions, please clarify the distance from the measuring device and the sensors, the type of signal being received, whether it is necessary to also send commends/data to the device, the desired sampling rate, the number of information bits being transmitted/received. Also wonder if you really mean an output sensor, since this typically means a signal is being sent to the device, where as a digital input sensor is typically used to describe a device which is providing input to a measurement device.  Please clarify this fact as well

I tried to answer coments: @Andy analogic (24V divided in 4 intervals for my case: 0-6V, 6-12V,...); I don't know the difference between a PLC and Arduino;

@Finbarr I am measuring magnetic field presence every one minute;

@Jens power most probably can be just one cable running all the lenght;

@itprorh66 the distance is bellow 100m; no comands will be sent back.

This seems like a classic problem for an embedded bus. In general most buses will let you wire all your sensors on a string (one set of wires winding around all of them) instead of every sensor being wired directly to the controller.  They all require a little bit of smarts at each connected device, but typically not very much.
You didn't mention the data rate, so I'll assume it is pretty low.
So, which bus?

I2C: 128 or 1024 devices, 2 wires (plus ground and power), 100 or 400 kbit/s (rarely up to 5 Mbit/s)
CAN: 127 devices, 2 wires, 40 kbit/s to 1 Mbit/s
LIN: 16 devices, 20 kbit/s to 1 Mbit/s
1-Wire: unlimited devices, 1 wire (plus ground), 16.3 kbit/s
RS-485: 256 devices, 2 wires (plus ground), 10 Mbit/s, allows very long distances (at lower speeds)
IrDA: what a TV remote control uses - not technically a bus, but it connects any number of devices to each other, without wires ;) 115 kbit/s, limited to about 2m distance

Many devices you might want to connect (ADCs, temperature sensors, etc) already support I2C. If whatever is in your sensor supports I2C, then that's your natural choice.  If not, then most ways of reducing the number of wires require some kind of microcontroller at each sensor - but it can be a very simple one. Almost every microcontroller out there supports I2C. The cheapest microcontrollers that support CAN are about a dollar.
RS-485 is a physical specification only, so it needs a protocol on top of it, typically Modbus or Profibus. This combination is probably the most common setup used in factories where lots of equipment sensors need to be connected.
The microcontroller option will require a bit of coding, no way around it.  The easiest is either an Arduino Nano or Raspbery Pi Pico.
P.S. To get a better answer, please add:

the data rate
the distances from sensor to central hub
your budget, and
what the digital sensor interface is currently


What's the basis for the selected buses? The selection seems a bit arbitrary. Something should also be mentioned about how they are meant to be used. If as op says his house is too full of wires, and we're at the scale of the whole house, I2C or 1-Wire is not what you want to use. RS485 or CAN would be more appropriate. (Or Ethernet, or WiFi)

@MrGerber True. The selection is low data rate buses that are commonly available in microcontrollers (hence no ethernet) and are multidrop rather than point-to-point (hence no USB). 1-Wire has no limit on number of devices, can be implemented on any microcontroller in code, and I think would work okay at whole house scale; it is limited to about 200-500m total wire length. I2C a bit more problematic, around 10m usually, but it works okay at slow speeds up to ~100m with CAT5. Not sure I'd recommend that per se, but if the sensors are I2C it may be an option.

Many things that support I2C only support a limited range of addresses, though, so it's hard to put more than a handful of identical parts on the same bus. It's also not good for long cable runs, given timing requirements and parasitic capacitances.

@Hearth True, I2C may not be the first choice. It can work at up to 100m at 10kbit/s, but it may not be the easiest thing to get running at those distances. Just offering that as an option depending on the connected devices
